# Issues with Python Pandas and Numpy for machine learning classification

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas, machine-learning

Here is what I am trying to do. There are two columns of original dataset, one is the full name of individuals (ie: Justine Davidson) and another as ethnicity (ie: English). I would like to train using Naive Bayes machine learning approach to predict people's ethnicity based on name features. To extract name features from the names, I break the full name into 3-character substrings (ie: Justine Davidson => jus, ust, sti, ... etc). The followings is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import re
import numpy as np
import nltk
from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier as nbc

# Get csv file into data frame
data = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\KubiK\Desktop\OddNames_sampleData.csv")
frame = DataFrame(data)
frame.columns = ["name", "ethnicity"]
name = frame.name
ethnicity = frame.ethnicity

# Remove missing ethnicity data cases
index_missEthnic = frame.ethnicity.isnull()
index_missName = frame.name.isnull()
frame2 = frame.loc[~index_missEthnic, :]
frame3 = frame2.loc[~index_missName, :]

# Make all letters into lowercase
frame3.loc[:, "name"] = frame3["name"].str.lower()
frame3.loc[:, "ethnicity"] = frame3["ethnicity"].str.lower()

# Remove all non-alphabetical characters in Name
frame3.loc[:, "name"] = frame3["name"].str.replace(r'[^a-zA-Z\s\-]', '') # Retain space and hyphen

# Replace empty space as "#"
frame3.loc[:, "name"] = frame3["name"].str.replace('[\s]', '#')

# Find the longest name in the dataset
##frame3["name_length"] = frame3["name"].str.len()
##nameLength = frame3.name_length
##print nameLength.max() # Longest name has !!!40 characters!!! including spaces and hyphens

# Add "?" to fill spaces up to 43 characters
frame3["name_filled"] = frame3["name"].str.pad(side="right", width=43, fillchar="?")

# Split into three-character strings
for i in range(1, 41):
    substr = "substr" + str(i)
    frame3[substr] = frame3["name_filled"].str[i-1:i+2]

# Count number of letter characters
frame3["name_len"] = frame3["name"].map(lambda x : len(re.findall('[a-zA-Z]', x)))

# Count number of vowel letter
frame3["vowel_len"] = frame3["name"].map(lambda x : len(re.findall('[aeiouAEIOU]', x)))

# Count number of consonant letter
frame3["consonant_len"] = frame3["name"].map(lambda x : len(re.findall('[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]', x)))

# Count number of in-between-string (not any) spaces
frame3["space_len"] = frame3["name"].map(lambda x : len(re.findall('[#]', x)))

# Space-name ratio
frame3["SN_ratio"] = frame3["space_len"]/frame3["name_len"]

# Vowel-name ratio
frame3["VN_ratio"] = frame3["vowel_len"]/frame3["name_len"]

# Recategorize ethnicity
frame3["ethnicity2"] = ""
frame3["ethnicity2"][frame3["ethnicity"] == "chinese"] = "chinese"
frame3["ethnicity2"][frame3["ethnicity"] != "chinese"] = "non-chinese"

# Test outputs
##print frame3

# Run naive bayes
featuresets = [((substr1, substr2), ethnicity2) for index, (substr1, substr2, ethnicity2) in frame3.iterrows()]
train_set, test_set = featuresets[:400], featuresets[400:]
classifier = nbc.train(train_set)

# Predict
print classifier.classify(ethnic_features('Anderson Silva'))

Name    Ethnicity
J-b'te Letourneau   Scotish
Jane Mc-earthar French
Li Chen Chinese
Amabil?? Bonneau    English
```

When I run the program, it has two problems:

1. This is a non-fatal issue and happens multiple times throughout the code but it still runs without terminating:

   ```
   See the the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
     frame3["space_len"] = frame3["name"].map(lambda x : len(re.findall('[#]', x)))
   C:\Users\KubiK\Desktop\FamSeach_NameHandling4.py:57: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
   A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
   Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
   ```
2. This is a fatal issue (terminated the program):

   ```
   Traceback (most recent call last): Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:\Users\KubiK\Desktop\FamSeach_NameHandling4.py", line 71, in <module>
       featuresets = [(substr1, ethnicity2) for index, (substr1, substr2, ethnicity2) in frame3.iterrows()]
   ValueError: too many values to unpack
   ```

Comment: You should post a sample of your initial dataframe so we have some data to work with.  Regarding your first question, try this instead frame3.loc[:,"space_len"] = frame3["name"].map(lambda x : len(re.findall('[#]', x)))

Comment: Thanks for the advice, sample data is added

Comment: Thanks.  So you want featureset to be a list of what?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I want the feature set to be subtr1 to substr40, as each substr is the 3-letter substring of the entire name. In the above example, I only include substr1 and substr2, but got the error.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because frame3 has more than 3 columns.

frame3.iterrows() is an iterator through tuples (index, row).
Here row is a pd.Series whose index is columns names, and values are all the values in the row.

Your frame3 dataframe has many columns: name, etnicity, name_filled, name_len, etc. 
You are trying to write all these values into three variables: substr1, substr2 and ethnicity2, hence the "too many values to unpack" error. To fix this, select just the columns you need:

```
featuresets = [(substr1, ethnicity2) for index, (substr1, substr2, ethnicity2) in frame3[['substr1', 'substr2', 'ethnicity2']].iterrows()]
```